# How do I use bound parameters with TSQLQuery.SQL

Tags: sql, pascal, lazarus

Im running a couple of queries (well attempting to) using Lazarus objects rather than programatically, I have my DB Connections and Transactions setup and interacting with my Queries and am reading and initial query into a TDBGrid. Now what I want to do is be able to click on a grid cell and select an ID value to use in a query.

I have a TSQLQuery object setup and linked to a source, I entered this into the SQL property:

```
SELECT * FROM tbl_accounts
WHERE tbl_accounts.ClientID = :AccID
```

However I can't work out how to pass my parameter into the object... My procedure looks like this:

```
procedure TtcheckHome.accResultsCellClick(Column: TColumn);
  begin
  selected := listAccounts.Fields[0].AsString;
  // accSelect.SQL.Text := 'SELECT * FROM tbl_accounts WHERE tbl_accounts.ClientID = 2';
  accSelect.Params.ParamByName('AccID').AsString := selected;
  textEdit.Text := accSelect.FieldByName('AccountNumber').AsString;
end;
```

This always returns with accSelect : Field name AccountNumber not found, if I remove any references to Params however and hardcode an ID into the query it works perfectly. This leads me to believe that my method for using bound parameters is wrong! What have I missed?

Comment: Can you show us `tbl_accounts` table definition?

Comment: you need to close accSelect, set the parameter value, and then open again

Comment: @DavidA You Sir, are a star, I'd never have got that working through looking at the Lazarus documents, if you want to add it as an answer I'll gladly accept it. A thousand and one thanks, I been messing around with this for 2 bloody days!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To refresh the query with the parameter value:

```
accSelect.Close;
accSelect.Params.ParamByName('AccID').AsString := selected;
accSelect.Open;
```

and what I do if you don't want to continually close and reopen the same query:

```
if accSelect.Params.ParamByName('AccID').AsString <> selected then
begin
  accSelect.Close;
  accSelect.Params.ParamByName('AccID').AsString := selected;
end;
if not accSelect.Active then
  accSelect.Open;
```